# How restrict multiple logins same user C# and Active Directory membership

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-membership

How to prevent multiple logins of same user using AD membership and C#?

I try to use MembershipUser.IsOnline but this is not suported by AD membership provider.

This is a code:

```
                MembershipUser muser = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                if(muser.IsOnline)
                {
                    //TODO
                }
```

But it catch this exeption: "LastLoginDate" is not supported by the Active Directory Membership Provider

Comment: Yes. I try to use this 'code' MembershipUser muser = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                    if(muser.IsOnline)
                    {
                        //TODO
                    } But it appears this exeption:  "LastLoginDate" is not supported by the Active Directory Membership Provider

Comment: you can edit your question and should put the code into a codebox in your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not with help of AD membership classes but still:

- Add user's SessionId to Application every time session starts.
- Add user's SessionId to his cookies

Every request you have to check if SessionId's match.

Answer (score 0):

that seems more an issue of configuration in your active directory, you may set your cache credentials in your network policy to 0, so you won't use the kerberos ticket cache.

Then you have to solve the next problem, that is how many logins do you allow in your network, this article describes one way to approach it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.05.utilityspotlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the situation I had was a little different, but I feel that the same principles can apply.  My situation was such that I had to make sure that user ID's were logged in from just one device at a time (Forms Authentication, by the way, not AD). When a user ID tried to log in to another device while still logged in to an existing device, it killed the session on their existing device while allowing them to log-in to the new device. I wrote up a solution on my original post on Stack Overflow:

[When the same user ID is trying to log in on multiple devices, how do I kill the session on the other device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the/15939899#15939899)